# How come my if else statement isn't executing properly

Tags: python, if-statement

```
a = input("enter your first name ")

for i in range(len(a)):
    for space in range(len(a)-i):
        print(end=' '*len(a))
    for j in range(2*i+1):
        print(a,end = '')
    print()
print()

if a == 'Allahyar' or 'allahyar':
    print(a+ ' is a boomer')
elif a != 'Allahyar' or 'allahyar':
    print(a+' has been sent to the pyramid realm')
```

in this code the if statement executes no matter what and it completely ignores the elif statement. any idea why?

Comment: You need to rewrite the condition as either `a == 'Allahyar' or a == 'allahyar'` or `a in ['Allahyar', 'allahyar']`. Or even simpler `a.lower() == 'allahyar'`. This is because how conditions are evaluated in your expression.

Comment: oh thanks so much I dont see how i missed this part  == ''   == ''

Answer (score 1):

Correct syntax to combine two conditions using logical `or` operator.

```
if var == "str1" or var == "str2":
```

You can also do it like this

```
if var in ["str1","str2"]:
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll expand on my comment. The reason you're getting the if condition always triggering is because you think that what you coded should equate to: "*variable a is equal to either 'Allahyar' or 'allahyar'*" but in reality it will get evaluated as two separate statements like so (brackets added for clarity):

`(a == 'Allahyar') or (bool('allahyar'))`

A non-empty string 'allahyar' will always evaluate to `True` so it's impossible for this combined expression to be `False`.

Comment: awesome thanks for the timely reply.. Im super new to stackoverflow and coding in general and my god this place is freakin awesome.. super fast replies with detailed explanations.. i love you guys :)

Answer (score 0):

as @pavel stated the correct code is  == ''   == '' I just got confused so I made an elif statement but the actual code was this a = input("enter your first name ")

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    for space in range(len(a)-i):
        print(end=' '*len(a))
    for j in range(2*i+1):
        print(a,end = '')
    print()
print()

if a == 'Allahyar' or a == 'allahyar':
    print(a+ ' is a boomer')
else:
    print(a+' has been sent to the pyramid realm')
```

there is no reason for the elif statement its just extra code to write for no reason.